# Regular False Position - Problem with recursion

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I am having some problems with my recursion program for false position method in python. For some reason, when I start my program, nothing is being outputted to console. It runs, but then it stops without doing anything. Was wondering if you could see any holes in my program.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import sys

sys.setrecursionlimit(10000);

def function(x):     
    return float((1/x) - (np.log(x)) + (np.log(2)))

def checkroot(a, b):
    if(function(a) * function(b) < 0):
        falsepositionmethod(a, b)

def processinterval(a, b):
     c = float(((a * function(a)) - (b * function(a)))/(function(b) - function(a)))
     return c
 
def falsepositionmethod(a, b):
    midpoint = processinterval(a, b)
    
    if((function(a) * function(midpoint)) < 0):
        return falsepositionmethod(a, midpoint)
    
    if((function(a) * function(midpoint)) > 0):
        return falsepositionmethod(midpoint, b)

    elif(np.abs(function(midpoint)) < 0.0005):
        return midpoint
    
    return print(midpoint)
    
def main():
    a = 0.1
    b = 20.0
    
    checkroot(a, b)
    print(falsepositionmethod(a, b))
    
main()
```

Comment: What does this code do? Give us some context, please.

Comment: It just runs the console (red button comes on), then ends saying restarting kernel.

Comment: Consider adding some logging to help you debug. The most common failure case in an algorithm like this would be if the values don't converge.

Comment: Console? Red button? Kernel? I don't know what any of those are. What's the *purpose* of this code? Describe it to us like we don't know what project you're working on or problem you're trying to solve (cause we don't).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that one of the first two conditions is always holding (i.e., `function(a) * function(midpoint)` is non-zero), and so  you never reach your termination condition. Move your if-statement `np.abs(function(midpoint)) < 0.0005` above the other two if-statements.

Comment: dam that was it : D . i feel stupid